# How to autopopulate location on a devise registration form with geolocation? (or equivalent solution)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation, devise

I am trying to automatically populate a city field on my devise registration form by using geolocation. I have copied the devise registrations_controller into my own controller folder and edited the action new as follows:

```
def new
resource = build_resource({})
respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :new }
@geo = GeoLocation.find(request.remote_ip)
resource[:city] = @geo[:city]
end
```

Here is what I have in the form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>  
<%= devise_error_messages! %>  
<p><%= f.label :city, 'City' %><br />  
<%= f.text_field :city %></p>
```

To be frank, I have been teaching myself rails/ruby for just a month and pretty sure I am making an easy mistake, but using devise has proven to be quite confusing when I try to customize it... Whats the best way to achieve this with devise? Should I be even editing the registrations controller? Thanks for any help.

**EDIT** 
Thanks for the answer. It makes sense, and I should have figured. In any case, it allowed me dig deeper. Now I have a form with a collection selector that automatically populates with the city where the IP is coming from. Here is the code that worked for me:

Controller:

```
   def new
    @geo = GeoLocation.find(request.remote_ip)
    @city = City.find_by_name(@geo[:city])
    resource = build_resource(:city_id => @city[:id])
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :new }
    end
```

Form:

```
    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <p><%= f.label :city_id, 'City' %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
```

Now my next step is to figure out how to let users add cities not in database and how to test all this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This command needs to be the last one in the controller action:

```
respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :new }
```

Any changes made to the resource after that won't be reflected in the rendered view.

Comment: Makes sense. Basic mistake on my part. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept the answer if it worked for you.